# Angular's JQ Lite functions (triggerHandler method) not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have an Angular.js app that uses some calendar inputs to select date ranges. The calendar inputs use jQuery UI datepicker. I'm quite aware of the dangers that can arise from using jQuery modules in an Angular app and kindly ask that we avoid opening that discussion in this thread.

Regarding, Angular and jQuery UI compatibility I have several functions and extensions which make the datepicker work nicely in the Angular app.

1. A custom datepicker directive
2. an `angular.element(el).triggerHandler('input')` method to update the controller scope (otherwise only the UI changes - even though the scope is watched it is not digested if triggered from jQuery UI events)

The problem I'm having is that the `triggerHandler()` is updating the controller scope in every browser except IE 11. I can confirm that it works in IE Edge, Safari, Chrome, FireFox and Opera.

**Here's my directive:**

```
angular.module('trip.directives',[])
  .directive('ccDatePicker', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element[0]).datepicker().on("change", function (e) {
                var date = element.val();
                scope.$apply( function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

**Here's my directive being called in html:**

```
<p class="field date black">
    <input type="text" id="newtrip-date-from" class="form-control date datepicker date-from" name="date-from" id="date-from" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" ng-model="startModal.dateFrom" cc-date-picker />
    <input type="text" id="newtrip-date-to" class="form-control date datepicker date-to" name="date-to" id="date-to" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" ng-model="startModal.dateTo" cc-date-picker />
</p>
```

**And here's my javascript datepicker callback that uses `angular.element(el).triggerHandler('input')` to update my controller scope. This is the part that works in every browswer except IE 11:**

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        onSelect: function(date) {
            var target = null;
            switch ( $(this).hasClass('date-from') ) {
                case true:
                    target = $(this).attr('id').split('from');
                    target = target[0] + "to";
                    $('#' + target).datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
                    angular.element($(this)).triggerHandler('input');
                    break;
                case false:
                    target = $(this).attr('id').split('to');
                    target = target[0] + "from";
                    $('#' + target).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
                    angular.element($(this)).triggerHandler('input');
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

If anyone knows a workaround for updating the scope for this event in IE 11 it would be really big help. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you do a `$scope.$apply` instead? That is the right api to trigger scope digest.  You can do `angular.element(this).scope().$apply()`

Comment: @JoseM The apply cycle is triggered by the directive when a change has made but I never thought to apply it from datepicker callback because the change value is not picked up. I'll give it a try thanks.

Comment: did you try to wrap the ` scope.$apply( function () {`
`                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);`
` });`
with *setTimeout()* ?

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes angular settimeout functions don't work in this case (tested this)

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes actually I only tested it in the directive now that I think about it. I'll try running some tests on the datepicker callback as suggested in this thread and update the thread later today

Comment: Unfortunately neither method worked. The reason is because in IE 11 angular doesn't detect the change at all when changed from a js event so calling an apply cycle will just apply the null field

Comment: Have you tried using `.trigger('input')` instead of just `triggerHandler`? The other thing, you are already using jQuery so angular.element($(this)) is the same as just doing $(this) so you can skip that step.

Comment: @JoseM - Yes, I tried that method before. Actually I did manage to fix it, I'll be updating with my answer soon in case anyone else finds this thread later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to fix this issue. In case anyone stumbles upon this thread, here's how I solved the problem:

As I'd expected, the problem was with the datepicker not sending a change event. To fix that, I manually updated model by getting the element's scope using `angular.element()` and running an apply function:

```
/* this first part checks for IE 11 */
if ( !(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject" in window === true) {
    /* now we assign the element's angular scope to a variable */
    var $scope = angular.element($('input[name="date-from"]')).scope();
    /* and use that scope var to run an apply cycle */
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        /* here we set the value on the target model 
           using jQuery */
        $scope.startModal.dateFrom = $('input[name="date-from"]').val();
    });
}
```

Finally, the full integration into the datepicker's on select callback was like this:

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        onSelect: function(date) {
            var target = null;
            switch ( $(this).hasClass('date-from') ) {
                case true:
                    target = $(this).attr('id').split('from');
                    target = target[0] + "to";
                    $('#' + target).datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
                    if ( !(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject" in window === true) {  // <= targets IE 11
                        var $scope = angular.element($('input[name="date-from"]')).scope(); // assign the elements scope to a var
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.startModal.dateFrom = $('input[name="date-from"]').val(); // sets the correct model value
                        });
                    } else {
                        angular.element($(this)).triggerHandler('input');
                    }
                    break;
                case false:
                    target = $(this).attr('id').split('to');
                    target = target[0] + "from";
                    $('#' + target).datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
                    if ( !(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject" in window === true) {
                        var $scope = angular.element($('input[name="date-to"]')).scope();
                        $scope.$apply(function () {
                            $scope.startModal.dateTo = $('input[name="date-to"]').val();
                        });
                    } else {
                        angular.element($(this)).triggerHandler('input');
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```